# Ratio's and Max Size

Tags: functional-equations

If I have a video of size:

```
 width: 640
 height: 480
```

and a screen of size:

```
 width: 1280
 height: 720
```

what is the equation to find the max width and height I can stretch the video too
and keep its ratio.

I can calculate the ratio like:

```
 ratio = width / height

 video ratio: 1.3

 screen ratio: 1.7
```

that's about as far as I can work out :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the corresponding measurements by each other: screen width by video width, screen height by video height. Then take the *smaller* of the two ratios, and that's the amount you can stretch the video by.

In this example, we have
$$\frac{\text{screen width}}{\text{video width}} = \frac{1280}{640} = 2$$
$$\frac{\text{screen height}}{\text{video height}} = \frac{720}{480} = 1.5$$
So you can stretch the video by a factor of $1.5$, making it $960\times720.$

Comment: This is assuming the screenwidth is always greater than the video width?

Comment: If the screen size is larger than the video size (both height and width) you'll end up with a number larger than 1; the method still works if the screen is smaller in one or both dimensions, you'll just end up with a number smaller than 1 to multiply by.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ratio of the widths is 2 and the ratio of the heights is 1.5, you can stretch the video by a factor of $\min(1.5,2)=1.5$ and it will still fit on the screen.
If you scale it up by a larger factor it will be too large in the vertical dimension.